# Размер пакетов от MS SQL не может быть больше 590 байт?

Tags: sql-server, сеть, windows-server-2008-r2

Здравствуйте! Не так давно обнаружил, что MS SQL сервер отправляет клиентам данные в пакетах размером не более 590 байт, создавая сильную фрагментацию, так как запросы обычно крупные, что отражено на скриншоте Wireshark:

[image: Wireshark-screenshot]

Я пробовал менять опцию `max packet size` на 1500, но размер пакетов не изменился даже после перезагрузки сервера. Я попытался провести диагностику проблемы и вот что удалось выяснить:

- Проблема не в MTU конечных компьютеров - везде значение стоит стандартное в 1500 байт.
- На пути между сервером и клиентами нет оборудования с MTU меньше 1500 байт.
- команда `ping -l 1472 -f` до любого клиента проходит успешно.
- TCP-соединения устанавливаются с размером окна в 1024 байта (8192 бита).

В связи с этим вопрос - по каким причинам параметр `max packet size` может не влиять на размер сетевых пакетов, отсылаемых сервером? Мои идеи насчёт неверной настройки оборудования или ОС иссякли. Возможно, проблема в самом MSSQL сервере? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

На сервере используется Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Клиенты - Windows 7.

Comment: `EXEC sp_configure 'network packet size', new_size` не помогает? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-network-packet-size-server-configuration-option

Comment: Попробуйте две вещи проверить: 1) текущие настройки сервера `select value_in_use from sys.configurations where name = 'network packet size (B)'` 2) не переопределяют ли сами клиенты размер пакета - при подключенном клиенте, определив его session_id посмотреть `select net_packet_size from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = ...`.

Comment: @Akina Попробовал сделать так. В ответе пишет, что значение 1472 изменено на 1472.

Comment: @i-one Первая команда выводит 1472. Вторая - 4096. В чем подвох?

Comment: Значит - нет, похоже это не SqlServer виноват. Если в Wireshark ткнуть на строчку (на вашем скриншоте) `TDS 590 Response (Not last buffer)`, то в деталях должно быть что-то наподобие `[8 Reassembled TCP Segments (4096 bytes): #1(436), #2(536), ... , #7(536), #8(444)] Tabular Data Stream > ... Length: 4096` - числа в скобках возле номеров должны давать в сумме полный (т.к. это _Not last buffer_) пакет. Т.е. SqlServer честно формирует TDS-пакет требуемого клиентом размера. Который далее, полагаю, отсылается по TCP через инфраструктуру, предоставляемую ОС.

Comment: @i-one Прошу прощения, я с самого начала не проверил работу остальных приложений с сетью. Собственно, такая же проблема, например, с FTP сервером и SMB протоколом. В общем, буду расследовать. Если появится интересная информация - сообщу. Спасибо за наводку!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я нашёл причину этой фрагментации - это отключенная функция **PMTU Discovery** в Windows. Если она отключена, протокол TCP будет отправлять пакеты на любые адреса с MTU 576. Цитирую [Майкрософт](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/900926/recommended-tcp-ip-settings-for-wan-links-with-a-mtu-size-of-less-than):

> Если отключить возможность определения PMTU, протокол TCP будет отправлять пакеты с размером MTU 576 байт и со снятым флагом «не фрагментировать».

Проблема была решена изменением значения ключа `EnablePMTUDiscovery` с 0 на 1 в ветке реестра `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`.

После перезагрузки компьютера SQL и все другие приложения стали отсылать пакеты по 1514 байт, несмотря на значение MTU самого интерфейса 1500. Честно говоря, я не совсем понимаю причины подобного поведения PMTU Discovery, но проблему удалось обойти понижением MTU интерфейса до 1486.

Comment: Эти лишние 14 байт - это MAC Header. Этот заголовок не учитывается в MTU, но учитывается Wireshark. Вы напрасно считали их проблемой.