# Принудительная установка размера пакета для MS SQL сессии

Tags: sql-server, сеть

В настройках сервера MS SQL есть опция `packet size`, которая отвечает за размер сетевых пакетов по умолчанию, отправляемых и принимаемых сервером.

Насколько я понял, это означает, что если клиент определяет другой размер пакета, эта опция для конкретной сессии меняет своё значение, так что при `packet size = 1500` на сервере, это значение может измениться на 4096, и 8192 в рамках конкретной сессии по желанию клиента.

Однако мне интересно, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы установленное на сервере значение `packet size` использовалось "принудительно"? То есть, возможно ли вообще сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог влиять на размер пакета при соединении с SQL сервером?

Comment: Вероятно, это продолжение вопроса [Размер пакетов от MS SQL не может быть больше 590 байт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687062/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82-ms-sql-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-590-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82).

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, но сейчас вопрос касается возможности специфической настройки MS SQL, а не проблем с ним. Нужно ли было задавать этот вопрос на странице старого?

Comment: Нет, вы всё правильно сделали. Я просто ссылку даю, так сказать, для будущих поколений. Чтобы контекст был понятнее. И чтобы вопросы были друг у друга в блоке «Связанные».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... возможно ли сделать так, чтобы установленное на сервере значение
>   *packet size* использовалось "принудительно"? То есть ... чтобы
>   пользователь не мог влиять на размер пакета при соединении с SQL
>   сервером?

Насколько мне известно - нет, нельзя.

Теоретически SqlServer мог бы принуждать клиентов к использованию пакетов определённого размера, однако, каких-либо настроек, которые бы фиксировали размер пакета для клиента, в SqlServer нет. И в этом, по-видимому, есть некая рациональность. Ниже несколько подробнее.

---

Общение SqlServer с клиентами происходит посредством протокола TDS (*Tabular Data Stream*, [спецификация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx)). Выдержка из спецификации протокола:

> 2.2.3 Packets
>   ...
>   At login time, clients MAY specify a requested "packet" size as part of the LOGIN7 message stream. ... Server
>   acknowledgment of changes in the negotiated packet size is transmitted
>   back to the client via ENVCHANGE token stream.
>   ...
>   2.2.7.8 ENVCHANGE
>   ...
>   Type 4 (Packet size) is sent in response to a LOGIN7 message. **The
>   server MAY send a value different from the packet size requested by
>   the client.** That value MUST be greater than or equal to 512 and
>   smaller than or equal to 32767. **Both the client and the server MUST
>   start using this value for packet size** with the message following the
>   login response message.
>   ...

гласит (вкратце) следующее. Клиент при логине может попросить установить размер пакета. В ответ сервер присылает подтверждение об изменении размера пакета. Однако (!) сервер может прислать *иное* значение размера пакета, чем запросил клиент. После чего и сервер и клиент *обязаны* использовать этот размер пакета при общении.

Т.е., формально сервер может установить другой размер пакета, чем хотел клиент, и клиент обязан подчиниться.

Простой эксперимент показывает, что это не только формальная возможность, но и фактическая реальность. Так, например, если запросить размер пакета 515 байт, то вместо 515 он будет установлен в *512* байт, вместо 517 байт - *516*. В диапазоне возможных значений (от 512 до 32767 байт) гранулярность возможного размера пакета составляет 4 байта. Наблюдаются, впрочем, несколько "аномалий" в диапазонах 8000...8192, 16192..16384, 24384..24576, и 32576..32767 байт - в них размер пакета устанавливается по нижней границе диапазона, и от запрошенного может не совпадать на 192 байта (гранулярность и "аномалии", вполне вероятно, могут зависеть от версии SqlServer).

Однако поскольку значительной разницы между запрошенным значением и фактическим не наблюдается, то можно сказать, что SqlServer, в среднем, к пожеланиям клиентов прислушивается.

Что могло бы быть, если бы в SqlServer существовала некая настройка, фиксирующая размер пакетов для клиентов?

Представим, что некое приложение делает bulk-загрузку данных на сервер. Такому приложению, для уменьшения издержек, выгодно установить большой размер пакета (скажем, 8Кб). Предположим, SqlServer урезает размер пакета для такого клиента до 512 байт. Это приведёт к повышению издержек на передачу данных, производительность загрузки просядет.

Обратная ситуация. Если клиент делает много мелких запросов и для оптимизации желает использовать маленькие пакеты (по 512 байт). Предположим, что в этом случае SqlServer, наоборот, устанавливает для такого клиента размер пакет значительно больше требуемого (скажем, 32Кб). Это означает, что в какой-то момент клиенту где-то придётся создать и содержать буфер в 32Кб, большая часть которого будет пустовать. Это может быть не страшно, если активное соединение одно, но если их по тысяче к сотне таких серверов - это будет серьёзный перерасход памяти.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. В любом случае, нагрузка на сеть существенно убавилось после решения проблемы с излишней фрагментацей.